# Bing maps. How can I get address by lat and long?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, street-address

Is it possible to get address(Country, City, street, etc) by latitude and longitude? 
(BingMaps version 7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's you're looking for is reverse geocoding - translating a coordinate into an address (as opposed to regular geocoding, getting coordinates from address information). The BingMaps 7.0 javascript library doesn't support this directly, but you can get this functionality from the Bing Maps REST services, and specifically the Locations service.

Check out both the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx) of the Locations service and the docs of the Javascript library where they provide [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427601.aspx) of calling that service from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

after all research I have got this query

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/point?includeEntityTypes=entityTypes&includeNeighborhood=includeNeighborhood&include=includeValue&key=BingMapsKey

this query is about to give us address after giving the latitude and longitudes.

read the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

Comment: I actually don't know where to put the latitude and longitude values. So, if any body knew please tell me?

Comment: point is a placeholder for latitude & longitude. E.g. https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.391489, 8.478757?key=mySecretKey